# Are Bremsstrahlung and the Unruh effect equivalent?

Tags: photons, qft-in-curved-spacetime, unruh-effect, synchrotron-radiation

[This paper](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.46.3450) argues that the absorption and emission rates from and to the thermal Unruh bath of a proton viewed in a coaccelerated frame is equal to the emission rated viewed from an inertial observer. 
However, I have seen [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0012132v1) (section 4.4) clearly stating that Synchrotron radiation and Unruh radion are not the same. 
Am I confusing two different types of radiation or do they refer to different effects? What am I missing?